Subspace topology corresponds to the induced topology of inclusion map, a specific proof
I'm trying to understand lemma 1.6 in Kallenberg's probability book, in which he shows that the induced topology of the "natural embedding" of a subset $A$ corresponds to the standard subspace topology defined by $A \cap \mathcal{T}$. Specifically,
Let $(S,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Let $A$ be a subset of $S$. Consider the "natural embedding" $\pi_{A}: A\rightarrow S$. Show the subspace topology $A\cap \mathcal{T}$ corresponds to the topology induced by this embedding, denoted as $\mathcal{T}_A$.
Since by definition, $\mathcal{T}_A$ makes $\pi_A$ continuous, we know that $\forall M\in \mathcal{T}$, $\pi_{A}^{-1}(M) = M\cap A \in \mathcal{T}_A$, thus, $A\cap \mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}_A$;
Conversely, $\forall B\in \mathcal{T}_A$, we want to show $B\in A\cap \mathcal{T}$.
Kallenberg's approach is to define $G \equiv (B\cup A^{c})^{o}$, where the complmenet and interior are wrt $S$, and then note that $B = A\cap G$.
I don't know how to prove the claim $B = A\cap G$. Certainly $A\cap G\subset B$, but what about the other direction? Thank you!
Edit: essentially I want to show, $\forall B\in \mathcal{T}_A$, where $\mathcal{T}_A$ is the initial topology, we have $B = A \cap (B\cup A^{c})^{o}$. For general $B$ this is certainly false, so the question is how do I use the fact that $\mathcal{T}_A$ is the coarsest topology making the inclusion map continuous to prove this set identity.

Just to get the notation straightened out for myself, we have:

A topological space $(S, \mathcal{T})$
A subset $A \subseteq S$
The inclusion $\pi_A : A \to S$
The subspace topology $A \cap \mathcal{T} := \{A \cap T : T \in \mathcal{T}\}$
The initial topology on $A$ defined by $\pi_A$, denoted by $\mathcal{T}_A$.


By definition, $\mathcal{T}_A$ is the coarsest topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $A$ such that $\pi_A : (A,\mathcal{T}') \to (S,\mathcal{T})$ is continuous.
It is easy to check that $\mathcal{T}_A = \{\pi_A^{-1}(T) : T \in \mathcal{T}\}$: we simply note that $\{\pi_A^{-1}(T) : T \in \mathcal{T}\}$ is a topology on $A$ which makes $\pi_A$ continuous, and that any topology on $A$ which makes $\pi_A$ continuous must contain $\{\pi_A^{-1}(T) : T \in \mathcal{T}\}$!
But now notice that $\pi_A^{-1}(T) = A \cap T$ for all  $T \subseteq S$! So,
$$\mathcal{T}_A = \{\pi_A^{-1}(T) : T \in \mathcal{T}\} = \{A \cap T : T \in \mathcal{T}\} = A \cap \mathcal{T}$$
and we are done.

Thanks for your answer! This is a nicer proof than the one I've seen elsewhere. But I do hope to understand Kallenberg's argument -- I feel it should be really simple. I made an edit to my question to emphasize the part I couldn't understand.

So I think the answer provided by diracdeltafunk is straightforward and classic, therefore I will accept this answer as the solution.
However, I do want to explain Kallenberg's argument here, in case anyone is interested.
$\forall B\in \mathcal{T}_A$, we know that $B\subset A$, and thus $\pi_{A}^{-1}(B\cup A^{c}) = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap A^{c}) = A\cap B = B$.
As a matter of fact, $\pi_A^{-1}((B\cup A^{c})^{o}) = B$. For if not, then there exists $T\in \mathcal{T}$ s.t. $\pi_A^{-1}(T) = B$, and $(B\cup A^{c})^{o} \subsetneq T$. But then, since $\pi_A^{-1}(T) = A\cap T = B$, we have $T\subset B \cup A^{c}$.
This contradicts $(B\cup A^{c})^{o}$ being the largest open set contained in $B \cup A^{c}$.
